# Mysqlbug: Could not find a text editor. (tried emacs)

Tags: mysql, centos

I want to check with what configurations mysql was configured. I found that mysqlbug can retrieve that info, but i'm getting the following error:

```
mysqlbug
Finding system information for a MySQL bug report
test -x 
Could not find a text editor. (tried emacs)
You can change editor by setting the environment variable VISUAL.
If your shell is a bourne shell (sh) do
VISUAL=your_editors_name; export VISUAL
If your shell is a C shell (csh) do
setenv VISUAL your_editors_name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that you can choose to use editor whichever you want vim, nano etc instead of emacs by exporting environment variable.

Just export VISUAL environment variable. Example usage:

```
export VISUAL=vim
```